# remove/ignore float from outer div

Tags: css, alignment, html, vertical-alignment

This may sound weird but i have some css which aligns mys divs. In one place i also use http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html which centers images.

Now i want my divs inside a larger div to go to another line if this one gets full. float: left seems to be the answer. The problem is it ruins my formatting. Including solution in the above link. I have this test code. If i remove the width and float it looks fine except it may take up too much space and not go to another line.

I was thinking i could use float on an outerdiv and center the image within. However float: left is still breaking it. I am hoping there is a way to remove the float so each div does go left but the div inside centers correctly not breaking my formatting.

```
<style type="text/css">
.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
.wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/*\*//*/
.wraptocenter {
    display: block;
}
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
/**/
div.c
{
background: red;
overflow: hidden;
min-width: 400px;
max-width: 400px;
}
div.c div
{
float: left;
}
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><style>
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style><![endif]-->

<div class="c">
<div>

<div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><span></span><img src="a.jpg" alt="/a.jpg"></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><span></span><img src="a.jpg" alt="/a.jpg"></div>
<div class="wraptocenter"><span></span><img src="a.jpg" alt="/a.jpg"></div>

</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

regular old `display:inline` can be used on the images themselves (or a container div). this will let the items flow onto multiple lines depending on the width of the enclosing div.

to center the top-level div, something like `margin: 0 auto` should do it (if the parent has a width) or the good old `<center>` tag if not.